# Rails Scaffolded Site, unable to add Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have tried a few times to add a single column of data to a table of mine and have been successful to a point. I am able to add the column and pull the attribute name into the show, edit, index, and form. However, anytime I try to add info on that attribute or update an existing row of data to include that attribute, the attribute (for every row) remains empty.

I have tried removing the column through the RemoveAttrFromModel, I even watched the schema.rb file as it added and removed the attribute of interest each time I did rake db:migrate, thinking that it may have had something to do with the add process, but to no avail.

What I am talking about is in my app > views > model(s) folder, if you make a new scaffolded model, you will see what I am talking about as I am pretty sure it gives you new, show, index, edit and _form documents.

I have already updated the new, show index, edit, and form files to take and display the new attribute.

Here is what I can do: 
add data into that attribute through the rails console.

Here is what I want to do: on the actual website(add data into that attribute value, edit the data, display the data from that attribute)

EDIT

Here's my _form.html.erb

```
        <%= form_for(@taster) do |f| %>
  <% if @taster.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@taster.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this taster from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @taster.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br>
    <%= f.select :state, [
      ["Alabama", "AL"],
      ["Alaska", "AK"],
      ["Arizona", "AZ"],
      ["Arkansas", "AR"],
      ["California", "CA"],
      ["Colorado", "CO"],
      ["Connecticut", "CT"],
      ["Delaware", "DE"],
      ["District Of Columbia", "DC"],
      ["Florida", "FL"],
      ["Georgia", "GA"],
      ["Hawaii", "HI"],
      ["Idaho", "ID"],
      ["Illinois", "IL"],
      ["Indiana", "IN"],
      ["Iowa", "IA"],
      ["Kansas", "KS"],
      ["Kentucky", "KY"],
      ["Louisiana", "LA"],
      ["Maine", "ME"],
      ["Maryland", "MD"],
      ["Massachusetts", "MA"],
      ["Michigan", "MI"],
      ["Minnesota", "MN"],
      ["Mississippi", "MS"],
      ["Missouri", "MO"],
      ["Montana", "MT"],
      ["Nebraska", "NE"],
      ["Nevada", "NV"],
      ["New Hampshire", "NH"],
      ["New Jersey", "NJ"],
      ["New Mexico", "NM"],
      ["New York", "NY"],
      ["North Carolina", "NC"],
      ["North Dakota", "ND"],
      ["Ohio", "OH"],
      ["Oklahoma", "OK"],
      ["Oregon", "OR"],
      ["Pennsylvania", "PA"],
      ["Rhode Island", "RI"],
      ["South Carolina", "SC"],
      ["South Dakota", "SD"],
      ["Tennessee", "TN"],
      ["Texas", "TX"],
      ["Utah", "UT"],
      ["Vermont", "VT"],
      ["Virginia", "VA"],
      ["Washington", "WA"],
      ["West Virginia", "WV"],
      ["Wisconsin", "WI"],
      ["Wyoming", "WY"]
    ] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :headline %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :headline %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :employmentStatus %><br>
    <%= f.select :employmentStatus, [
      ["Employed Full Time", "employedFullTime"],
      ["Employed Part Time", "employedPartTime"],
      ["Freelancing", "freelancing"],
      ["Not Employed but Looking", "notEmployedbutLooking"],
      ["Not Employed", "notEmployed"]
    ] %>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show your _form.html.erb ??

Comment: Are you getting unpermitted parameters in your rails console log? Check that. IF that is your problem then @Stavros Souvatzis answer has got you covered.

Comment: the one that i'm interested in is the :title attribute

Comment: Can you show the relevant model and controller? I am still not getting the problem. You can create new records with title attribute but can't get the title attribute part working for older records? Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used generate scaffold, you have to fix the strong parameters on your controller... After your actions, under "private" you will see something like:

Having seen your edit on your question, I assume your model is taster, so this code should go to `tasters_controller.rb`:

```
def taster_params
    params.require(:taster).permit(:name, :age, :city, :state, :headline,
                            :description, :employmentStatus, :title)
end
```

You should add your new fields to the permit section of this definition.

Comment: what file is this in?

Comment: I don't know how you've built your app, but I believe this should be in tasters_controller.rb and you should add :title in the permit(...) section.

Comment: by the way, you're awesome. this worked. thanks a bunch. so a scaffold would do this, but if I just add the attribute after the scaffold then it won't, right?

Comment: Yes, the scaffold is just a build helper. You generate it once. After that, it's handicraft...